# How to create Classlink testing account for simulation sso login

Tags: testng, single-sign-on

Please let me know how to create a classlink account for testing sso flow, I have seen the documentation but didn't find anything related to creating classlink account

Answer (score 0):

You need to reach out to their support who will set you up with the testing accounts.